# post ajax data to PHP and return data

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, post

How can i post some ajax data to the controller function and get it back? For I want to post one integer to the function, and get another integer (total votes for the item which ID is posted), and on success i want to echo that vote count.
I dont know how can i post the "id" to the controller function.  Please see my code:

```
//post this integet
the_id = $(this).attr('id'); 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: the_id,
            url: "http://localhost/test/index.php/data/count_votes",
            success: function(){
                //the controller function count_votes returns an integer.
                //echo that with the fade in here.

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {data:the_id},
            url: "http://localhost/test/index.php/data/count_votes",
            success: function(data){
               //data will contain the vote count echoed by the controller i.e.  
                 "yourVoteCount"
              //then append the result where ever you want like
              $("span#votes_number").html(data); //data will be containing the vote count which you have echoed from the controller

                }
            });
```

in the controller

```
$data = $_POST['data'];  //$data will contain the_id
//do some processing
echo "yourVoteCount";
```

**Clarification**

i think you are confusing

```
{data:the_id}
```

with

```
success:function(data){
```

both the `data` are different for your own clarity sake you can modify it as

```
success:function(vote_count){
$(span#someId).html(vote_count);
```

Comment: Did you mean after postng the ID to controller function, i should just echo inside the function? I want to show the $data on success with `$("span#votes_number").html(number);`

Comment: see the `$data` will receive the ID you have sent from the client side on the base of that `ID` you probably will do some processing and calculate the `total votes` then `echo` the `voteCount` that you have calculated and receive it in the `success` callback then you can display the `voteCount` where ever you want i'll modify the answer a bit have a look

Comment: thanks man. it works but Im just wondering why it will work if i `echo "yourVoteCount";` in the number in the controller, but wont work if i `return yourVoteCount;` in that case i wont get any data on success. whats the reason? thanks again.

Comment: echo prints output to the page to be displayed in the browser, im not sure but you can try using `print` instead of echo ... i myself is not very sure why return cant be used may someone else will explain it better..

Answer (score 5):

For the JS, try

```
data: {id: the_id}
...
success: function(data) {
        alert('the server returned ' + data;
    }
```

and

```
$the_id = intval($_POST['id']);
```

in PHP

Comment: Thanks, this is what im looking for. I need to post the ID to the controller and controller will return another integer ($vote_count), i need to post that on sucess. But if i understand correctly your example alerts the ID which im posting to the controller, not the data from the controller.

Answer (score 5):

So what does count_votes look like?  Is it a script?  Anything that you want to get back from an ajax call can be retrieved using a simple echo (of course you could use JSON or xml, but for this simple example you would just need to output something in count_votes.php like:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];

function getVotes($id){
    // call your database here
    $query = ("SELECT votes FROM poll WHERE ID = $id");
    $result = @mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    return $row->votes;
}
$votes = getVotes($id);
echo $votes;
```

This is just pseudocode, but should give you  the idea.  What ever you echo from count_votes will be what is returned to "data" in your ajax call.

Comment: count_votes simply gets the (integer) number of votes from the db for the ID posted. In my ajax function, On success I want to get this number so that i can echo like `$("span#votes_number").html(number);`

Comment: So using your example, the value that you output from your "count_votes" script will be interpreted as the "data" javascript variable, so $("span#votes_number").html(data);

Comment: thanks man. Im just wondering why it works if i echo the $votes in the controller but wont work if i "return" the $votes?

Comment: The ajax response is looking for some type of data being output to it.  Since PHP is run server side, you need to "echo" out some kind of response to the client side code.  That's the only way for it to receive the output.