# How to use AJAX POST request to trigger a series of PHP code?

Tags: php, ajax

So, right now I am trying to make it so that an AJAX post request can trigger this conditional statement:

```
if(isset($_POST['purse'])) {
             if($_POST['purse'] == true) { <---- Removed
                    if($nexttime <= time()) {
                        /* Some DB queries etc.. */
                        $output = array();
                        array_push($output, "<div class='alert alert-success'>You are successful!</div>");
                        echo(json_encode($output));
                    } else {
                        /* Other stuff... */
                    }
                   }
                   /* Echos work here */
                 }
```

And so far I have tried this:

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#purse').click(function() {
                $.ajax(
                {   
                    type : "POST",
                    url: "petty.php",
                    data: {purse: 'true'},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }

                });
            });
        });
```

But that doesn't seem to trigger it. This is all for an effort to make it so the page executes whatever it is supposed to, depending on which button the user clicks, without refreshing the page and I heard AJAX is the way to go for that, but I honestly can't figure it out and have tried tutorials but they don't do what I am trying to do, from what I have seen.

Form:

```
<form action="petty.php" method="post">
        <div class="subheading mb-5 text-center"><br>Steal a few purses.
        <button type="submit" name="purse" id="purse" class="btn btn-dark center-block">Submit</button>
            <div class="subheading mb-5 text-center"><br>Forge checks.
            <button type="submit" name="checks" id="checks" class="btn btn-dark center-block">Submit</button>
            <div class="subheading mb-5 text-center"><br>Steal cars.
            <button type="submit" name="cars" id="cars" class="btn btn-dark center-block">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

EDIT: Well, my issue is that I am trying to push all messages, that the user will be able to see upon clicking a button, into an array and using echo(json_encode($output)) to push it all to AJAX so that it can be outputted to the browser, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Make the button type button instead of submit or the form will posts entire page..

Comment: Making it a button instead of submit doesn't work, when I click it, nothing happens then.

Comment: You are sending key as `'pursel'` in the data, but checking on key `'purse'`. Also what is the value of purse in `data: {'pursel' : purse}`?

Comment: That's actually a good catch, I mean't 'purse' : purse. I was just experimenting with AJAX since I have never done them before. All I am trying to do with it is send that POST request so that the conditional sets off.

Comment: Remove the comma in “ type: POST,” line since it’s a last line, check for js errors and add console.log(123) to see if function gets called..

Comment: It doesn't appear that the AJAX function is even being called, there's nothing being logged in the console.

Comment: Try to remove it outside document.ready or add onclick=“myfunction1();” to the button then create it and put your Ajax call there instead..

Comment: The AJAX call works and everything is dandy now, except that the echo statements that go through and get sent to my AJAX, from PHP, won't get shown. Editing code.

Comment: Put echo’s outside and inside each conditional statement so you know what’s going on such as echo ‘1’, echo ‘2’...  Not sure why you need array for the output..

Comment: I needed the array, because there is usually more than one message that is displayed  to the user after a certain action is done.

Comment: Ok.. actually because it’s Ajax you can’t just use echo to get it back instead try this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/6616615/10634638

Comment: If you want to use echos you can get it back as a html string and then append it to the div https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/jquery-tutorial/jquery-ajax-get-and-post-requests.php

Comment: That doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. I want to send pre-defined echo messages from PHP to AJAX and show them to my users, I am still very confused.

Comment: I'm having a hard time saying this here, but my big issue is that I have many echos spread throughout the many conditionals in the PHP code after isset($_POST['purse']) and AJAX seems to only output any echo statement is if it is between the first and lasts brackets, that's my big predicament. Even doing an array and adding onto it doesn't work, the array just outputs blank.

Comment: There is more than one way to do it but you have to have a div to put your output like in the last link I sent with $(‘#result’).html(data); If you use regular post you display html generated for the whole page, with Ajax you refresh a part of the page..

Comment: That's not the issue though. The issue is that AJAX isn't getting any of the echo statements in my many conditionals, it is almost skipping over them, it only outputs where I've marked in the code above, if I put an echo statement there, other it won't show anything and I have no clue why.

Comment: Does it work if just do if(true) for the condition.. Also you should be using fiddler, for monitoring requests/responses so you will know if there is an error, plus have error catching inside Ajax call..

Comment: I removed that second if statement and it works, but it keeps displaying "<div class='alert alert-danger'>You must wait 60 seconds between crimes!</div> even though it shouldn't be showing that, and all the other code executes fine so I have no clue why it would be doing this.

Comment: You don’t need array just echo each line as you would for regular page..

Answer (score -1):

You're using

```
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     data: {'purse' : purse},
     type : "POST"
});
```

but we don't see the definition of 'url' or 'purse' anywhere. Did you debug it using Chrome/Firefox Developer Tools and check if it actually sends the ajax request?

Also, you should first check the existence of the ['purse'] key in your php code and then check validity. You're only checking existence, so the if statement will be entered any time you send the ajax, regardless of whether 'purse' actually contains anything.

Comment: Honestly, the 'purse' was just me messing around. All I was intending to do is for the user to click a button, for AJAX to recognize which button was clicked, according to id, and to send out a Post request so that a keyword like 'purse' could be read by the conditional isset($_POST['purse'])

Comment: Your code should work then. Did you debug it by now?