# Modal receiving wrong data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a list with information from a database, next to each record there is a button to edit the record data. The problem is when I try to send the id of the registry I want to edit, I have always received the same output, the simple word: Array.

This is the table:

```
<th><?php echo $row_usuario["id_employee"]; ?></th>
<td><?php echo $row_usuario["nome"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row_usuario["email"]; ?></td>
<td>
    <a href="#Edit" id="custId" data-toggle="modal" data-id=" '.$row_usuario['id_employee'].'">
        <i class="material-icons" style="color:#2A6F46">edit</i>
    </a>
</td>
```

The ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Edit').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var rowid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url : 'list_emp.php',
            data :  'rowid='+ rowid,
            success : function(data){
            $('.fetched-data').html(data);//Show fetched data from database
            }
        });
     });
});
```

Query part:

```
//database connection include before this
if($_POST['rowid']) {
    $id = $_POST['rowid'];
    //here is the problem, i'm not receiving the real id, just the word "Array" and i can't run the query because this
}
```

Modal:

```
<div class="fetched-data">Here i want to show the form with the info to be edit</div>
```

Can someone help me find the error?

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
 $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url : 'list_emp.php',
        data :  {rowid: rowid}
        success : function(data){
        $('.fetched-data').html(data);//Show fetched data from database
        }
    });
```

Like here shown [post ajax data to PHP and return data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616539/post-ajax-data-to-php-and-return-data)

Answer (score 0):

> next to each record there is a button to edit the record data

so i think you need class instead of id on your edit button
so change your html to this:

```
<th><?php echo $row_usuario["id_employee"]; ?></th>
<td><?php echo $row_usuario["nome"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row_usuario["email"]; ?></td>
<td>
    <a href="#Edit" class="fancyEditButton" data-toggle="modal" data-id=" '.$row_usuario['id_employee'].'">
        <i class="material-icons" style="color:#2A6F46">edit</i>
    </a>
</td>
```

and on your ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fancyEditButton').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var rowid = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url : 'list_emp.php',
            data :  'rowid='+ rowid,
            success : function(data){
                $('.fetched-data').html(data);//Show fetched data from database
            }
        });
    });
});
```