# How to submit the user data in registration table using AJAX to mysql table without refresh?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the problem of not submitting the user registration data (such as email, username, password) in a register table `tbl_register` on submit button click.

I am using PHP with AJAX so that my page not refreshes on submit click and data is send to mysql table using action php page `registersubmit.php`.

I have files as 
1) `register.php` - which has register and login form
2) `registersubmit.php` - which receives the submit click
3) `connection.php` - to make database connection.

code for above files are as follows:

1) register.php

```
<div class="form-wrap">
                        <div class="tabs">
                            <h3 class="signup-tab"><a class="active" href="#signup-tab-content">Sign Up</a></h3>
                            <h3 class="login-tab"><a href="#login-tab-content">Login</a></h3>
                        </div><!--.tabs-->

                        <div class="tabs-content">
                            <div id="signup-tab-content" class="active">
                                <form class="signup-form" action="" method="post">
                                    <input type="email" class="input" name="user_email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email">
                                    <input type="text" class="input" name="user_name" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username">
                                    <input type="password" class="input" name="user_pass" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password">
                                    <input type="submit" class="button" name="registersubmit" id="registersubmit" value="Sign Up">
                                </form><!--.login-form-->
                                <div class="message_box" style="margin:10px 0px;"></div>
                                <div class="help-text">
                                    <p>By signing up, you agree to our</p>
                                    <p><a href="#">Terms of service</a></p>
                                </div><!--.help-text-->
                            </div><!--.signup-tab-content-->

                            <div id="login-tab-content">
                                <form class="login-form" action="" method="post">
                                    <input type="text" class="input" name="user_login" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email or Username">
                                    <input type="password" class="input" name="user_pass" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="remember_me">
                                    <label for="remember_me">Remember me</label>

                                    <input type="submit" class="button" id="loginsubmit" name="loginsubmit" value="Login">
                                </form><!--.login-form-->
                                <div class="message_box" style="margin:10px 0px;"></div>
                                <div class="help-text">
                                    <p><a href="#">Forget your password?</a></p>
                                </div><!--.help-text-->
                            </div><!--.login-tab-content-->
                        </div><!--.tabs-content-->
                    </div><!--.form-wrap-->


<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            tab = $('.tabs h3 a');

            tab.on('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                tab.removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');

                tab_content = $(this).attr('href');
                $('div[id$="tab-content"]').removeClass('active');
                $(tab_content).addClass('active');
            });
        });


        </script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

               var delay = 2000;

               $('#registersubmit').click(function(e){

                   e.preventDefault();

                   var user_name = $('[name="user_name"]').val();

                   if(user_name == ''){
                       $('.message_box').html(
                       '<span style="color:red;">Enter Your Name!</span>'
                       );
                       $('[name="user_name"]').focus();
                       return false;
                   }

                   var user_email = $('[name="user_email"]').val();

                   if(user_email == ''){
                       $('.message_box').html(
                       '<span style="color:red;">Enter Email Address!</span>'
                       );
                       $('[name="user_email"]').focus();
                       return false;
                   }

                   if( $('[name="user_email"]').val()!='' ){
                       if( !isValidEmailAddress( $('[name="user_email"]').val() ) ){
                           $('.message_box').html(
                           '<span style="color:red;">Provided email address is incorrect!</span>'
                           );
                           $('[name="user_email"]').focus();
                           return false;
                       }
                   }

                   var user_pass = $('[name="user_pass"]').val();

                   if(user_pass == ''){
                       $('.message_box').html(
                       '<span style="color:red;">Password cannot be empty!</span>'
                       );
                       $('[name="user_pass"]').focus();
                          return false;
                   } 

                   $.ajax
                           ({
                           type: "POST",
                           url: "registersubmit.php",
                           data: "name="+user_name+"&email="+user_email+"&password="+user_pass,
                           beforeSend: function() {
                           $('.message_box').html(
                           '<img src="Loader.gif" width="25" height="25"/>'
                           );
                           }, 
                           success: function(data)
                           {
                           setTimeout(function() {
                           $('.message_box').html(data);
                           }, delay);
                           }
                           });



            });

            $('#loginsubmit').click(function(e){

                        e.preventDefault();

                        var user_name = $('[name="user_name"]').val();

                        if(user_name == ''){
                           $('.message_box').html(
                           '<span style="color:red;">Enter Your Name!</span>'
                           );
                           $('[name="user_name"]').focus();
                           return false;
                        }

                       var user_email = $('[name="user_email"]').val();

                       if(user_email == ''){
                           $('.message_box').html(
                           '<span style="color:red;">Enter Email Address!</span>'
                           );
                           $('[name="user_email"]').focus();
                           return false;
                       }

                       if( $('[name="user_email"]').val()!='' ){
                           if( !isValidEmailAddress( $('[name="user_email"]').val() ) ){
                               $('.message_box').html(
                               '<span style="color:red;">Provided email address is incorrect!</span>'
                               );
                               $('[name="user_email"]').focus();
                               return false;
                           }
                       }

                       var user_pass = $('[name="user_pass"]').val();

                       if(user_pass == ''){
                           $('.message_box').html(
                           '<span style="color:red;">Password cannot be empty!</span>'
                           );
                           $('[name="user_pass"]').focus();
                              return false;
                       } 

                        $.ajax({
                                   type: "POST",
                                   url: "loginsubmit.php",
                                   data: "name="+user_name+"&email="+user_email+"&password="+user_pass,
                                   beforeSend: function() {
                                   $('.message_box').html(
                                   '<img src="Loader.gif" width="25" height="25"/>'
                                   );
                                   }, 
                                   success: function(data)
                                   {
                                   setTimeout(function() {
                                   $('.message_box').html(data);
                                   }, delay);
                                   }
                                   });


                    });


            </script>
            <script>
                //Email Validation Function 
                function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
                    var pattern = /^([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+)*|"((([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))*(([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.)+([a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.?$/i;
                    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
                };
            </script>
```

2) registersubmit.php

```
<?php
if ( ($_POST['name']!="") && ($_POST['email']!="")){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

include('connection.php');

/* check connection */
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
    exit();
}

//insert query for registration
$insertSql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_register`(`Email`, `UserName`, `Password`) VALUES ('$email','$name', '$password')";

if ($conn->query($insertSql) === TRUE) {

}else{

    printf("Error: %s\n", $conn->error);

}

}
?>
```

3) connection.php

```
<?php

    // set the timezone first
    if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) {
        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
    }

    //create a mysql connection
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','');

    //check connection
    if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Connection Failed".$conn->connect_error);
    }   

    //connect database
    mysqli_select_db($conn, "my_db");

?>
```

Please help, after that i will solve the same problem for login also. But for now no entry received in my `tbl_register` table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [post ajax data to PHP and return data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616539/post-ajax-data-to-php-and-return-data)

Comment: but my database connection is ok and the only thing is data is not posted in the table

Comment: @RobinSingh what do you think about the code above and the problem in it?

Comment: Print your post method and console in ajax, check all the data passed correctly or not

Comment: Also use prepare statement to prevent sql injection

Comment: ok i will try that

Comment: @RobinSingh your console.log() suggestion worked thanks

Comment: can you also show how you pass form data using json as currently i have just used someone's login and signup code from codepen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200630/discussion-between-robin-singh-and-rinku-yadav).

Comment: Please click the link above to see the demo of how pass data in json format

Answer (score 0):

Try This >

```
<div class="form-wrap">
    <div class="tabs">
        <h3 class="signup-tab"><a class="active" href="#signup-tab-content">Sign Up</a></h3>
        <h3 class="login-tab"><a href="#login-tab-content">Login</a></h3>
    </div><!--.tabs-->

    <div class="tabs-content">
        <div id="signup-tab-content" class="active">
            <form class="signup-form" id="signup-form" name="signup-form" action="" method="post">
                <input type="email" class="input" name="user_email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email">
                <input type="text" class="input" name="user_name" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username">
                <input type="password" class="input" name="user_pass" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button btn" id="registersubmit">Sign Up</a>
            </form>
            <!--.login-form-->
            <div class="message_box" style="margin:10px 0px;"></div>
            <div class="help-text">
                <p>By signing up, you agree to our</p>
                <p><a href="#">Terms of service</a></p>
            </div><!--.help-text-->
        </div><!--.signup-tab-content-->

        <div id="login-tab-content">
            <form class="login-form" id="login-form" name="login-form" action="" method="post">
                <input type="text" class="input" name="user_login" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email or Username">
                <input type="password" class="input" name="user_pass" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="remember_me">
                <label for="remember_me">Remember me</label>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button btn" id="loginsubmit">Login</a>
            </form><!--.login-form-->
            <div class="message_box" style="margin:10px 0px;"></div>
            <div class="help-text">
                <p><a href="#">Forget your password?</a></p>
            </div><!--.help-text-->
        </div><!--.login-tab-content-->
    </div><!--.tabs-content-->
</div><!--.form-wrap-->


<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        tab = $('.tabs h3 a');

        tab.on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            tab.removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');

            tab_content = $(this).attr('href');
            $('div[id$="tab-content"]').removeClass('active');
            $(tab_content).addClass('active');
        });
    });


</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var delay = 2000;
    $('#registersubmit').click(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            var user_name = $('[name="user_name"]').val();
            if (user_name == ''){
                $('.message_box').html(
                '<span style="color:red;">Enter Your Name!</span>'
                );
                $('[name="user_name"]').focus();
                return false;
            }

            var user_email = $('[name="user_email"]').val();
            if (user_email == ''){
                $('.message_box').html(
                '<span style="color:red;">Enter Email Address!</span>'
                );
                $('[name="user_email"]').focus();
                return false;
            }

            if ($('[name="user_email"]').val() != ''){
                if (!isValidEmailAddress($('[name="user_email"]').val())){
                        $('.message_box').html(
                        '<span style="color:red;">Provided email address is incorrect!</span>'
                        );
                        $('[name="user_email"]').focus();
                        return false;
                }
            }

            var user_pass = $('[name="user_pass"]').val();
            if (user_pass == ''){
                $('.message_box').html(
                '<span style="color:red;">Password cannot be empty!</span>'
                );
                $('[name="user_pass"]').focus();
                return false;
            }
            var registerFormData = jQuery("#signup-form").serialize();


            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "registersubmit.php",
                    data: registerFormData,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                    $('.message_box').html(
                            '<img src="Loader.gif" width="25" height="25"/>'
                            );
                    },
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.message_box').html(data);
                    }, delay);
                    }
            });
    });

    $('#loginsubmit').click(function(e){

                e.preventDefault();
                var user_name = $('[name="user_name"]').val();
                if (user_name == ''){
                        $('.message_box').html(
                        '<span style="color:red;">Enter Your Name!</span>'
                        );
                        $('[name="user_name"]').focus();
                        return false;
                }

                var user_email = $('[name="user_email"]').val();
                if (user_email == ''){
                        $('.message_box').html(
                        '<span style="color:red;">Enter Email Address!</span>'
                        );
                        $('[name="user_email"]').focus();
                        return false;
                }

                if ($('[name="user_email"]').val() != ''){
                    if (!isValidEmailAddress($('[name="user_email"]').val())){
                            $('.message_box').html(
                            '<span style="color:red;">Provided email address is incorrect!</span>'
                            );
                            $('[name="user_email"]').focus();
                            return false;
                    }
                }

                var user_pass = $('[name="user_pass"]').val();
                if (user_pass == ''){
                    $('.message_box').html(
                    '<span style="color:red;">Password cannot be empty!</span>'
                    );
                    $('[name="user_pass"]').focus();
                    return false;
                }
                var loginFormData = jQuery("#login-form").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "loginsubmit.php",
                        data: loginFormData,
                        beforeSend: function() {
                        $('.message_box').html(
                                '<img src="Loader.gif" width="25" height="25"/>'
                                );
                        },
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $('.message_box').html(data);
                            }, delay);
                        }
                });

    });
</script>
<script>
    //Email Validation Function 
    function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = /^([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+)*|"((([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))*(([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.)+([a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.?$/i;
            return pattern.test(emailAddress);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: what is changed in this

Comment: I have added serialize here : var registerFormData = jQuery("#signup-form").serialize();